# Passing notification bar value to another activity in android

Tags: android, push-notification

I have created a app to show a push message in notification bar and I tried to pass a variable to second activity

here is the code

```
    public void showBarMassage( int resVal){
     final int id1 = resVal;
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Intent myI;
            PendingIntent myPI;
            NotificationManager myNM;
            myI =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ClaimPage.class );
            myI.putExtra("id",id1);
            System.out.println(id1);
            myI.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            myPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,myI,0);
            myNM =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Notification MyN = new Notification();
            MyN.icon =R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            MyN.tickerText = "Loyalty Message";
            MyN.number=id1;
            MyN.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            MyN.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            MyN.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            MyN.setLatestEventInfo(

                    getApplicationContext(), "Congratulation!!", "You have loyalty reward... ", myPI
            );

            myNM.notify(1, MyN);

        }
    });
}
```

when I access the value in second activity it always become null

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        if(extras.containsKey("id"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_claim_page);
            String msg = extras.getString("id");
            System.out.println(msg);

        }
```

why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try somethinf like this and check I have tested this it works!!

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourClass);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("id", yourID);

    PendingIntent notifyIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Comment: check my edited answer i have tested it it should work for you!

Comment: and through bundle you can get Your extras in your next activity